# Retrieve only contacts with numbers

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-contacts-api

I've built an app that pulls contacts from your google account. However, I can only use contacts that have a phone number.

I thought about pulling all the contacts and just filtering out those that don't have numbers, but I can only pull 100 contacts at a time (or else it returns an empty result), which means that if only 3 out of the 100 contacts have phone numbers, it will show only 3. This will become a tedious process if there is 10 000 contacts to sift through.

This is my current request url:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=100&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken
```

If it makes any difference, the app is built in PHP (CodeIgniter).

Is there any way that I can make the initial call to google to just return those contacts with phone numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by checking if there is a `next` link in the response and calling the same function again, with that link as an added argument.

```
foreach($result['feed']['link'] as $link) {
    if($link['rel'] == 'next') {
        $url = $link['href'] . '&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
        $this->googleimport($url);
    }
}
```

What's very important to note is that you need to manually add the `oauth_token`. This took me ages to figure out, and I only realised that after comparing my start link with the one retrieved from the response.

This then checks if I already have an accesstoken and if that token is valid, then retrieves the next set of records. I save all the records to a temporary database and do all my processing from there.

Answer (score 2):

Why not issue multiple queries if the initial one doesn't contain enough of contacts? You can use start-index to offset the subsequent queries: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters

Comment: In the end this is what I did. Should have answered my own question. Upvote for suggesting it though.